# how to get the values from a dictionary in the sorted-order of the keys?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

i have a problem with my python class. it contains a method that goes through all the keys of a multi_dimensional dictionary. The dictionary keys may be in  the following order           (1->(2,3),2->(5,6)). the problem is when the method attempts to get the keys, sometimes it gets them in the right order (1,2) and sometimes it gets them in the wrong order (2,1). any help will be appreciated. below is a very simple example of what the code might look like

```
class tree:
  tree_as_string = ""
    def __init__(self):
      self.id = ""
      self.daughters = {1 = 'node0', 2 = 'node1'}
    def get_as_string(self):
      s = ''
      for key in self.daughters:
         tree_as_string = s.join([tree_as_string, key])
      return tree_as_string
```

Comment: Repeat after me: Dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: There are no class methods there.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered  ( @Daniel Roseman )  ;)

Comment: if you do not change anything you should get always the same order for the keys. This is not exactly "unordered" although in practice it is said this way

Answer (score 3):

Note that dictionaries are unordered so in order to be sure that values would be handled in the ordered format you need to sort them first. Please find sample below:

```
d={1:{2:'tst', 3:'tst2'}, 4:{...} }

for key in sorted(d):
    for skey in sorted(d[key]):
        #do something
```

OR something like this:

```
from operator import itemgetter

d={1:{2:'tst', 3:'tst2'}, 4:{6:'tst7', 7:'tst12'} }

for key, val in sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(0)):
     for skey, sval in sorted(val.items(), key=itemgetter(0)):
        print key, skey, sval
```

This means that in your case:

```
class tree(object):

    tree_as_string = ""

    def __init__(self):
      self.id = ""
      self.daughters = {1 = 'node0', 2 = 'node1'}

    def get_as_string(self):
      s = ''
      for key in sorted(self.daughters):
         tree_as_string = s.join([tree_as_string, key])
      return tree_as_string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sorted (which I would suggest because it reduces your code even further example is below), or just call sort on keys.  Sort doesn't return a value, it just sorts whatever list is provided.

```
class tree:
  def __init__(self):
     self.id = ""
     self.daughters = {10: "test10", 2 : 'node2', 1 :'node1', 0 : 'node0'}

  def get_as_string_using_sorted(self):
    ''' Makes me happy'''
    return  '->'.join(str(k) for k in sorted(self.daughters))

  def get_as_string(self):
     s = '->'
     keys = self.daughters.keys()
     keys.sort()
     return  s.join(str(k) for k in keys)


t = tree()
print t.get_as_string()
print t.get_as_string_using_sorted()
```

---

Side note I changed your code a bit.

1. I fixed your dict syntax its k:v verus k=v
2. I initialized tree_as_string ="" you defined a class variable but never used it.
3. I added str(key) because key is an int.
4. Added more test numbers
5. changed s to ->
6. Simplified your for loop.

Comment: sorted() does not work as the daughter attribute is a dictionary n it returns an error. "'dict' object has no attribute 'sorted'"

Comment: Dont know what you are talking about, the code above works.  I fixed multiple errors you had.

Comment: @trey you have to sort the keys, you cannot sort the dict.